# How do I integrate NFT uses?

Tags: nft, signature, verify

I am developing a ticketing application. How can I make an NFT have a single use with the "uses" parameter, then when the user shows up to the event and verifies his ownership of the wallet with the NFT through signature, uses goes to 0?

I have read the docs, but I am still confused on the execution.

I would appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can [burn](https://spl.solana.com/token#burning)  the NFT once you are done with it.

You can create a `program` that automates things for you.

e.g. create `use` instruction where the program burns/transfers the NFT and you can store all the data like when `user` used his NFT etc...

Comment: I don’t necessarily want to burn the token, I want the token to not be “usable”. Can I for example exempt this token from signing a transaction because we may be using a signature request to prove ownership of NFT on our end. 

Can a signature bring uses from 1 to 0?